# Is "humbleness" a word?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

I am curious if "humbleness" is a word that can be used in place of the word "humility."

Example usage: A certain amount of humbleness is necessary to fit in with the office environment.

Comment: I suppose it is; but why not use *humility*? We should not be so proud as to invent new words when we have old ones.

Comment: Google Books claims [199,000 written instances of "humbleness"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22humbleness%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), so I think this is General Reference.

Comment: @fumble Fingers Sounds like a form of address for someone, but I can't think who...'Your Humbleness'!

Comment: @WS2: I personally would tend to interpret *humbleness* more in terms of the semi-facetious *"Welcome to my humble abode"*. That's to say, it would make sense to speak of the *humbleness* (lowly, of modest calibre) of one's circumstances, for example. Whereas I only associate *humility* with an emotional state of self-abasement, so it only works for *people*, not *things* (real or abstract).

Comment: @WS2  - more likely , Your Highness.., My Humbleness!!

Comment: @Josh61 You jest, but I am old enough to remember when people, writing letters to someone of importance (such as the editor of The Times) would end 'I beg to remain, Sir, your humble and obedient servant'.

Answer (score 2):

[humbleness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Humbleness)- a humble feeling; "he was filled with humility at the sight of the Pope"

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=humbleness,%20humility&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,humbleness;,c0;.t1;,humility;,c0) Humbleness is a less common word compared to humility as shown.